# Basic internal messaging DB design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to create a basic internal messaging system. The only 'special' consideration is a user can send a message to multiple recipients and a receiver of a message can Reply To All (if applicable). This is what I currently have:

```
MESSAGE TABLE
- thread_id
- message_id
- subject
- content
- date_sent
- from (FK to user_id)
- to (FK to user_id(s))

READ TABLE
- message_id (FK)
- recipient (FK to user_id, limit one un-read message per thread)
- read (boolean)
```

Does this DB design seem sufficient for an internal messaging system, or is it lacking anything / any way to improve it?

Comment: Regarding your "thread" concept. Apparently you want to have messages to be part of a given thread (I suppose you generate a new thread ID whenever someone writes a new message instead of answering to another message) and sort them on date_sent. But there is no way to have sub-branches of threads when someone answers to a previous message. Is this ok?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by 'sub-branches'? If someone answers to a previous message, wouldn't that just be a continuation of the existing thread?

Comment: A sends a message. B answers to A. C answers to B answering to A. D answers to A. E answers to B. C Answers to D. This would be, more or less: (A(B(C)(E))(D(C))) While you will have, temporally: ABCDEC (sorry but in comments it's hard to draw graphs) - so you have no specific link between the last message from C and the D message C is answering to. So I'd suggest adding a "In-reply-to" field which is a FK to message_id, even if all message are parts of the same thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there's a many-to-many relationship between messages and recipients. I would therefore factor that out into a join table; you may as well put the "read" flag on that join table.

That would give you something like:

```
MESSAGE TABLE
- thread_id
- message_id
- subject
- content
- date_sent
- from (FK to user_id)


MESSAGE_RECIPIENT TABLE
- message_id (FK)
- recipient (FK to user_id)
- read (boolean)
```

Your requirement to show only one unread message for a thread is a display issue, and I'd keep it out of the database. In your front-end code, you'd have logic to show the lesser of the actual number of unread messages and 1 when calculating the number of unread messages to show.

To find all recipients for a message (so you can do "reply all"), you need to join to the MESSAGE_RECIPIENT table, as follows:

```
select u.email_address
from   users u, 
       message m, 
       message_recipient mr
where  u.user_id   = mr.recipient
and    mr.message_id = m.message_id
and    m.message_id  = $whateverYourCurrentMessageIDis
```

(apologies for the archaic join syntax)

Comment: By "limit one unread message" I mean that if a user is in a thread, and ten people reply all in that thread, it will show one un-read message instead of ten. In addition, wouldn't separating the recipient table out like that complicate the matter of 'reply all' if there are multiple users in the thread. How exactly would that work?

Answer (score 3):

```
user
    user_id   

message
    thread_id (surrogate id to grant easy access to whole conversation)
    message_id
    parent_message_id (message replied on can be used to show replies in tree-view form. FK to message)
    subject
    contect
    date
    from_id (FK to user)

message_user
    message_id (FK to message)
    user_id (FK to user_id)
    status (readed, deleted, new....)
```

"Limit one unread message" should be handled by query getting count thread_id with status='new'.